# Intellij IDEA: Run Scala REPL Console on a remote machine.

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, proxy, read-eval-print-loop

I am wondering if it is possible to run Intellij's scala console process on a remote machine.

**The Problem**

I am developing a scala application on my local machine, but it needs to run on a remote machine.

What I am hoping for, is to launch the console process (that executes code) remotely and connect the console view/editor in IntelliJ to it - naturally with access to the local classes I am developing. I.e., this is a setup that is a little similar to launch an process remotely and then connecting the debugger.

**A little background**

The application (which builds on Spark) needs to talk a lot with servers that are on the same network as the remote machine. Running the console process on the remote machine will help *a lot* with port/hostname/proxy configurations. It will also improve performance, but that is secondary in this problem.

I have ssh access to the remote machine, so it is easy to setup proxies/ssh-tunnels.

Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the Terminal tab in IntelliJ, SSH to the machine, and use SBT from there?  I do this all the time.